# tcolorbox keyword behaves differently on a local compilation

Tags: tcolorbox

I'm using the example provided by the excellent *tcolorbox* p15 to use **newtcbox**.

```
 \newtcbox
    {\xmybox}[1][red]{on line,
    arc=7pt,colback=#1!10!white,colframe=#1!50!black,
    before upper={\rule[-3pt]{0pt}{10pt}},boxrule=1pt,
    boxsep=0pt,left=6pt,right=6pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt}

    The \xmybox[green]{quick} brown \xmybox{fox} \xmybox[blue]{jumps} over the
    \xmybox[green]{lazy} \xmybox{dog}
```

While Im able to compile this on Sharelatex, there is always a Package error on my local compilation :

> "! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/on line' and I am
>   going to  ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it"

All the packages are up to date, so I don't see why "*on line*" is a problem here

Comment: Probably because your claim that "every packages are up to date" is not true. Check the log-file, it tells you the package version.

Comment: Or maybe the way I call the update is wrong : I do it through apt-get which returns me "texlive-latex-extra is already to the last available version". Btw the version in the log is Package: "tcolorbox 2014/02/06 version 2.70 text color boxes"

Comment: A tex system that you install with apt-get and similar tools is often outdated. You need a standalone texlive 2016 if you want an up-to-date system. My tcolorbox is from 2016/07/14.

Comment: OK : this could explain why I was searching for something that doesn't exist. SO I'd remove the texlive-latex-base through apt-get to install it from compilation ?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question for some other readers : indeed as pointed by Ulrike Fischer a complete (and heavy) [indidividual texlive installation](http://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) solved this problem. 
The Debian/Mint/Ubuntu Latex packages are to be avoided.